# Combining MEF and IoC container

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, mef

I primarily use NInject as my IoC container, and is very happy with it - don't want to change that. But some things I want to import using MEF. The thing is, I want the imports to created by the IoC container as the imports can have dependencies to things that I've registered in the NInject IoC.

So, my question is: can I import the type of exports in some way, so I can hand it over to NInject for creation or is there an object factory of some kind that I can override in MEF?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac 2.1 [integrates](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MefIntegration) pretty well with MEF. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/nblumhardt/archive/2009/03/16/hosting-mef-extensions-in-an-ioc-container.aspx) by Nicholas Blumhardt about how it works.

Comment: Great - thanks. I'll dive into the Autofac Adapter and see if I can do the same thing with NInject.